# Steam not starting in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64bit

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, steam

I tried almost everything I could find online but steam still doesn't start. I installed steam on Mint 16 and it worked perfectly. But I like Ubuntu better so I hope there is a way to fix that.

Note: I would like a solution without having to reinstall another distro and I would like to keep using Ubuntu 12.04LTS. Until the next LTS comes out.

When I run steam from the terminal I got message below:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 12.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0_client)
/home/shayne/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 755:  3139 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) $STEAM_DEBUGGER "$STEAMROOT/$PLATFORM/$STEAMEXE" "$@"
mv: cannot stat `/home/shayne/.steam/registry.vdf': No such file or directory
Installing bootstrap /home/shayne/.local/share/Steam/bootstrap.tar.xz
Reset complete!
Restarting Steam by request...
Running Steam on ubuntu 12.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME has been set by the user to: /home/shayne/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0_client)
/home/shayne/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 755:  3251 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) $STEAM_DEBUGGER "$STEAMROOT/$PLATFORM/$STEAMEXE" "$@"
```

Answer (score 0):

Update -- this worked for me.  Is hopefully the interim solution:

1. remove proprietary video drivers
2. reboot
3. run steam, let it update
4. reinstall drivers
5. reboot

from: 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2192756&p=12956602#post12956602

> Re: Starting Steam creates a seg fault
>   It is known problem with steam, it happens since some time. Pretty messed thing.
>
> If you freshly installed steam its first run has to be done on.... gpu open source drivers, not proprietary. If you have proprietary drivers installed remove them, reboot pc, start steam, let steam to update itself, after it you can install proprietary drivers back and have steam running.

Comment: not sure this is solution; after rebooting next day -- Same Error!